# Ceiling fan's light-cord not turning it on

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a ceiling fan which has two cords, one to control the fan and one for the light. The cord for the fan works well.

The cord for the light was pulled once, switching the light off. But now pulling it doesn't turn the light on. It seems to never go completely back in, so when it's pulled, you don't really hear the click sound it used to make.

Is there any simple way to fix that?

(There is a switch in the wall, which, when turned off, cuts all power to the fan so that both the fan and light turn off.)

Comment: The pull switch for the light is broken, check and replaced it.  Turn off breaker first, don't trust switch

Comment: @crip659 Thanks. I was hoping there was some way to just "pop" it back. I would be fine with doing it once and never touching it again. Any chance that would work? (And by the way - thanks for the warning not to trust the switch.)

Comment: Most of those switches are inexpensive and not really repairable.  Would not trust switch not to break/not work again.  Would probably need to take fan down to try to fix, might as well just replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix with the power off you can open it up
Find the 2 wires that go to the switch and tie them together with a wire nut or
Other type of terminal splice.

These switches are inexpensive and available on line but are usually not repairable.
They can be found online as cheep as 1.50$ and 5$ at your local store.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid any work with wires in order to avoid any danger of electrical shock. But if something has to be done and if I can't find a switch (or as a temporary fix) your suggestion sounds good. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes these pull chain switches jam and just need to be freed, usually replacement is required.

Comment: If you turn off breaker and check with a meter or voltage tester that there is no power, then you are safe.

Comment: Usually there are other things on the same circuit so switching off the breaker shuts those off too. I would switch it off at the wall then put tape over the switch. Then as I disassembled the light, I would test to insure that there is no hot wire present.

Comment: @jim Stewart , I fully agree with you, but in many cases ceiling fans may have 2 hots from the same breaker. A few years back I received a write up for locking out a switch (with a clamp lock) , I did not have to pay because the switch had a on / off and I had it locked out. It is possible to have a 3 way and in this case the breaker should be used ( note 3 way switches do not have on / off markings) . Do I still use a switch with a clamp lock? Yes but I also do live work also at times so I would follow osha requirements as a recommendation just in case the neutral was switched + test for live

Comment: What device do you use to lock a wall switch?

Comment: @jim Stewart I use 439B grip tight circuit breaker lock by master lock, I usually have several of these in my vest pockets. When clamped onto a switch Handel and closed they will support a padlock and tag with a minimum of 15 lb pull force if I remember the osha requirement correctly. Note my locks all have my name and phone number on them this suffices for a “who to contact tag”  you would be surprised how many people will flip a switch with tape only.